# Arithmetic derivative of sums of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Take the sums of divisors of an odd perfect square. Then check to see when the arithmetic derivative is congruent 0 mod 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first few odd $n$ for which the arithmetic derivative of $\sigma(n^2)$ is divisible by $4$ are $1, 13, 15, 29, 51, 53, 63, 67, 73, 77, 79, 97, 99, 113, 123, 133, 135, 157, 161, 163, 171, 175, 185, 191, 195, 197$.  This sequence doesn't seem to be in the OEIS (yet).

Comment: Wow thank you so much

Comment: are you going to add it or should I?